# Select if else sql

Tags: sql

I have two table say `T1` and `T2` and one column `C` is common to both. I need an SQL query in which if `C` is `null` in `T1` it will select from other table.

I tried writing `SELECT` statement in `THEN` clause but not running. Don't know is there any `IF ELSE` clause in SQL.

```
Select C, case when c = null Then Select c from T2
from T1
```

Comment: they need to be joined first, is there a field where they can be joined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better, most RDBMSs support `COALESCE`, which lets you check multiple values and return the first non-null value.

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.C, T2.C) AS C
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.[Primary Key] = T2.[Primary Key]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was thinking to avoid join... but yes.. this is working perfectly. Though I have used NVL.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to need is a union

```
select c from t1
where c is not null
union
select c from t2
where c is not null
```

Now you get all the columns `C` from `T1`and `T2` in one result set but only if not null.

Well of course if this has simplified your problem too much you need to work with a join

```
    select coalesce(t1.c,t2.c) as c
      from t1
 left join t2 on (t2.id = t1.foreign_id)
```

This assumed that `T2.ID` is the primary key and related to `T1` with `T1.FOREIGN_ID`

It is important that you do a left join because otherwise you only get `T1` rows when the row also exists in `T2`.

Comment: Are union results are  sequential i.e result set contains rows from T1 and then T2 ? Anyways I have used joined to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in TransactSQL?

I like the first answer, however you could also do it this way...

```
select case t1.C
    when null then t2.C
    else t1.C
    end as [testC]
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.PKID = t2.PKID
```